# Django - Why do datatables work selectively?

Tags: jquery, python, django, datatables

I am playing around with datatables in django. In one instance I had a table to which I gave an added `id=product_tables`. In that template all I added was (base template had  bquery , datatablesjs cdn) :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#product_tables').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

This converted my table into a datatable with pagination, search, ordering etc. However when I was displaying the entries from a `model` as a table datatables dont seem to work even though in both instances the data is being imported into the template as a dictionary. There are TONNES of posts about datatables with js and everyone seems to employ a different strategy with a lot of them using django 1.4 or older.

Comment: Datatables is a client-side JQuery library and has nothing to do with Django. You need to show how you're rendering your `#product_tables` element in order to begin to get a sense of what's wrong.

Comment: You said "This converted my table into a datatable with pagination, search, ordering etc."; so what is it that is not working?